# Not getting current lat long

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I am developing Application in which I want to get Latitude and Longitude when button is clicked. But it shows always 0. My code is as below.
AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.java

```
package com.example.gpstracking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class AndroidGPSTrackingActivity extends Activity {

Button btnShowLocation;

// GPSTracker class
GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    btnShowLocation = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

    // show location button click event
    btnShowLocation.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {        
            // create class object
            gps = new GPSTracker(AndroidGPSTrackingActivity.this);

            // check if GPS enabled     
            if(gps.canGetLocation()){

                double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
                double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

                // \n is for new line
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Your Location    is    - \nLat: " + latitude + "\nLong: " + longitude, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
            }else{
                // can't get location
                // GPS or Network is not enabled
                // Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
                gps.showSettingsAlert();
            }

        }
    });
}

 }
```

And Second class is as below.

GPSTracker.java

```
      package com.example.gpstracking;

      import android.app.AlertDialog;
      import android.app.Service;
      import android.content.Context;
      import android.content.DialogInterface;
      import android.content.Intent;
      import android.location.Location;
      import android.location.LocationListener;
      import android.location.LocationManager;
      import android.os.Bundle;
      import android.os.IBinder;
      import android.provider.Settings;
      import android.util.Log;
      import android.widget.Toast;

     public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude = 37.422006; // latitude
double longitude = -122.084095; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    Log.i("*******", "Inside constructor");
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        Log.i("*******", "Inside get Location");
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("*******", ""+isGPSEnabled);
        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        Log.i("*******", ""+isNetworkEnabled);
        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GPS:"+isGPSEnabled+"NEtwork:"+isNetworkEnabled, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                Log.i("*********", "Inside isGPSEnabled");
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            0,
                            0, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        Log.i("*********", locationManager.toString());
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            Log.i("*********", location.toString());
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                            Log.i("*********", "Lat:"+latitude+"Long:"+longitude);
                        }Log.i("*********", location.toString());
                    }
                }
            }
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                Log.i("*********", "Inside isNetworkEnabled");
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        0,
                        0, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Location Changed called", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    latitude =location.getLatitude();
    longitude = location.getLongitude();
}

public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}


public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

I also added following permissions in manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Can anyone please tell me where I am going wrong. I tried to get lat long through network provider but they varies so much. Even for same location lat long from network is different.

Thanking you in advance..

Comment: Network Location provider isn't very accurate for accuracy you should use GPSProvider that usually take a little longer to find a location but has a better position.  From your update I dont get your problem anymore.

Answer (score 1):

When you create your location listener it will take sometime before actually getting a location, you may want to change the creation of your gpsTracker class from the onClick or at least save the instance you create on first click until you destroy it, perhaps after getting a location, so you dont create it every time causing to create another location Listener.

You could use a handler to pass a msg to your activity once the location is aquired.

Your **Handler** could be something like this:
Create a public Handler you your activity

```
public Handler handler;
```

Then add this to your onCreate Method

```
handler = new Handler(new Handler.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(msg.what == 0){
                //do the methods that require knowing your location you location
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

And your `GPSTracker` class you add this to your on onLocationChanged:

```
Message msg = new Message();
msg.what = 0;
((AndroidGPSTrackingActivity)mContext).handler.sendMessage(msg);
```

You can read about Handlers [here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html#handler).

Comment: @ Gabriel Netto
I am not getting lat long even after 10 mins.

Comment: you may need to add `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        0,
                        0, this);` but as long as you are connected to wifi and gps is active or you have a active data connection you should still get a location after sometime.

Comment: I am using that in my code inside if condition of isGPSEnabled.

Answer (score 1):

try this way...

```
LocationManager locManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
                locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,1000L,500.0f, locationListener);
                Location location = locManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                if(location != null)                                
                {
                    double latitude = location.getLatitude();
                    double longitude = location.getLongitude();



                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of the devices will not get gps quickly when you call `LocationListener`. So what i done was I tried to get it in AsyncTask with the condition `latitude and longitude !=0`. If this condition get executed successfully then we got both the latitude and longitude. After that you can do what ever your want.

This is the code in Async Task

```
public class GPSLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {  
        boolean running =true;
                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute()
                {  
                    super.onPreExecute(); 
                    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(RoadMaintenanceActivity.this);
                    progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                          public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                              getgps.cancel(true);  
                          }
                    });
                    LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE); 
                    LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();  
                    mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, mlocListener);    
                    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                    progressDialog.setMessage("Getting GPS Location...");
                    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                    progressDialog.setProgress(1);
                    progressDialog.show();

                } 

                @Override 
                protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                    // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
                 }

                @Override 
                protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
                {  
                        progressDialog.cancel(); 
                }

                @Override
                protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
                    boolean isDataSubmitted = false; 
                 while(!isDataSubmitted)
                        {   
                            if(longitude !=0 && latitude!=0) 
                            {
                                    //Do your operation here 
                                isDataSubmitted = true;
                            } 
                    }

                    return null;    
                } 
     }
```

It should work.

Comment: Unless he changes this to his own Activity class he will need a way to let his activity know he is got a location. And you did miss the method that would dismiss the progress dialog.

Comment: @GabrielNetto  Yeah i agree with you if he needs to get notified then he can use handler. But if latitude is must to go for next process of his app async task will be useful. Progress Dialog dismiss will work if he press the back button. You can see that method in `OnPreExecute`.

Comment: I he needs that to proceed I agree with you. On the dialog note it should be dismissed after successfully getting a location.

Comment: Yes `onPostexecute()` it get dismissed. Because postexecute will takeplace when the process gets completed

Comment: Just saw what you did on doInBackground quite hackish. I would use the onLocationChanged method to what you used an AsycnTask if a while to accomplish. Check my answer and just imagine dismissing the dialog on the onLocationChanged method and creating it on the onClick assuming you are in the same class.